# Decision time for residence permit of family member of EEA citizen

Tags: eu-citizens, eu-spouses, residence-cards

Within EEA countries, family members / spouses of a citizen of another EEA country can apply for a residence permit under favourable conditions. This is explained [here on europa.eu](https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/residence/documents-formalities/non-eu-family-members-residence-card/index_en.htm) specifically for EU countries.

**Question 1:** What is an official source that explains the rules that apply to the EEA in general (not just EU)?

**Question 2:** According to the above-linked website, within the EU, applications for such a residence permit must be processed *within at most 6 months*. This is important since these residence permits expire 6 months after moving countries—thus a new one should be issued before then. Are there similar rules on processing times for the EEA (not just EU)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is an official source that explains the rules that apply to the EEA in general (not just EU)?

The rules for the EEA are the same.  The directive 2004/38/EC has been "incorporated into the EEA agreement."  See https://www.efta.int/eea-lex/32004L0038.

> According to the above-linked website, within the EU, applications for such a residence permit must be processed within at most 6 months. This is important since these residence permits expire 6 months after moving countries—thus a new one should be issued before then.

The six-month limit is not in fact particularly important because failure to have the card cannot lead to expulsion, only to an administrative sanction, and if the application is submitted promptly then any such sanction would be unjust.  In fact, I have heard that in some places it is not particularly rare for the six-month deadline to be exceeded.

Also, for a family that has moved to a new country, the status of the non-EU/non-EEA family members does not depend on the possession of a residence card from the previous place of residence -- it is the same whether they have arrived from another EU/EEA country or from a non-EU/non-EEA country.  And the terms under which the residence cards lose their validity are not necessarily uniform; this is governed by national law, subject to limits set forth in the directive, rather than by the directive itself.

(Note too that these cards are properly called "residence cards" rather than "residence permits" because they do not confer permission to reside; instead they are evidence that the bearer has a right to reside that is not subject to the host country's discretion.)

> Are there similar rules on processing times for the EEA (not just EU)?

As noted above, the rules are the same.

In comments, you write

> There are practical issues though such as being able to travel and return. Without a valid residence card, how can the family member prove the right to re-enter?

There certainly are practical issues.  Without the card, the family member can use whatever proof of relationship would be used on initial arrival or to apply for the card itself.  Such practical issues are certainly significant, and for certain purposes, for example obtaining employment, the card is an administrative requirement even if it is not a legal requirement.

> We've been explicitly told that there is no guarantee of being let back in until the application is processed, for which the projected time is well over 6 months

There's no guarantee ever.  For example, if the family member commits violent crimes showing that the family member is a threat to public safety, the family member can be excluded from the country of residence.  But if the family member is armed with evidence of the family relationship, evidence of the EU (or EEA) citizen's citizenship, and evidence that he or she is traveling to join (or traveling with) the EU (or EEA) citizen, it would not be legal for the border authorities to deny admission without first finding that the family member is a threat to public safety, public health, or public policy.

> Furthermore, in some places processing this application is a prerequisite to being able to access some basic things, such as opening a bank account, getting a medical prescription, a cell phone contract or even just public library access.

This is a significant problem.  The solution will be different in different host countries (in part because the specific things that are difficult without the card will be different in different countries).  The general solution is to complain to [SOLVIT](https://ec.europa.eu/solvit/index_en.htm), where the EEA countries are also in scope.

Comment: There are practical issues though such as being able to travel and return. Without a valid residence card, how can the family member prove the right to re-enter? We've been explicitly told that there is no guarantee of being let back in until the application is processed, for which the projected time is well over 6 months. Furthermore, in some places processing this application is a prerequisite to being able to access some basic things, such as opening a bank account, getting a medical prescription, a cell phone contract or even just public library access.

Comment: This is why I was looking to read the exact rules, and why I am looking at _The right of residence of family members of a Union citizen who are not nationals of a Member State shall be evidenced by the issuing of a document called "Residence card of a family member of a Union citizen" **no later than six months** from the date on which they submit the application. A **certificate of application** for the residence card shall be issued immediately._ Neither of these things are happening in practice, but at least I know that to point to now.

Comment: @Szabolcs I've added to the question some reactions to these comments.

Comment: Thank you once again for your valuable responses throughout several years both here and Travel.SE. Do you know if EEA citizens and their spouses have the right to equal taxation with local citizens, and if yes, where this rule is explained? Once again, I can find sources that apply to the EU, but not the EEA.

Comment: @Szabolcs income taxation?  Some other kind of tax?  As far as I know all EU and EEA countries tax people based on residence, regardless of citizenship.  But I am no expert.  And I don't know what EU law has to say on the matter, if anything.

Comment: Thanks for the response! If I figure it out, perhaps I'll post a self-answered question. As usual, it's much easier to find [information that is relevant for EU countries](https://taxation-customs.ec.europa.eu/eu-individuals-rights-under-eu-law_en) than information about whether the same applies to the broader EEA. I was looking into income taxation and the right to be taxed as married with one's non-EEA spouse before they get their residence card.

Comment: Sadly, it's all too common that some countries' officials refuse to follow the rules, [even after a good scolding by a higher authority](https://www.eftasurv.int/newsroom/updates/iceland-takes-necessary-measures-implement-eea-rules-facilitating-freedom-movement) ...

Comment: @Szabolcs interesting.  Apparently Sweden also has some, er, difficulties implementing the free movement directive, and Ireland's implementation looks a bit idiosyncratic, though this is probably at least partly because it isn't in the Schengen area.  In any event, I'm far less familiar with EEA rules as I have no direct experience with EEA countries or EEA nationals. But if the taxpayer in question is married to a non-EEA third country national and the treatment of that situation is the same as for a citizen of the taxing country who is married to a non-EEA third country national without a...

Comment: ... residence permit, that would comply with the principle of nondiscrimination.  That is, it's acceptable to discriminate against non-EEA third country nationals, but if they get special treatment for being married to a citizen of the taxing country then it seems to me that the same special treatment ought to be extended to those who are married to citizens of other EU and EEA countries; otherwise the difference in treatment would be vulnerable to a challenge on the principle of nondiscrimination.